# C programming - integers and characters

Tags: c, integer, ascii

I ripped this from an ebook on C programming.

[image: Source]

I understand that ASCII representations of the characters '0' and '9' are integers, so I understand the compatibility with the integer array. I am simply not sure how the shown output is computed? There input is the code itself.

What does this statement mean?

```
++ndigit[c-'0'];
```

So, is the program essentially checking if the input is one of the first 10 installments of of the ASCII code table?
[ASCII CODE](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Comment: `c-'0'` converts one of the ASCII characters `'0'` through `'9'` into the equivalent integer value.

Comment: Also in the ebook is a statement that claims the use of single quotes ' ' converts whatever is within the quotes to its int equivalent. That is, 'A' = 65. Is this true?

Comment: `'A' == 65` is true on many but not all systems (counter-example: IBM mainframes using EBCDIC).  It is always true that `'A'` is an `int` (in C; in C++, it is a `char`), and represents the numeric code for the letter capital A.

Answer (score 3):

No, it doesn't.

`c - '0'` subtracts the (not necessarily ASCII) character code of the character `0` from  that of `c`. This will yield a number between 0 and 9 if `c` is a digit. Then, the resulting integer is used to index the zero-initialized `ndigit` array using the `[]` operator, and the prefix increment operator (`++`) is then used to increment the element at that particular index.

By the way, the code is erroneous at multiple places. I suggest you switch to another book because this one appears to be either outdated and/or encouraging the use of several types of bad programming practice.

First, `main()` doesn't have a return type, which is an error. It needs to be declared as `int main()` or `int main(void)` or `int main(int, char **)`. Older compilers had the bad habit of assuming an implicit `int` return type if it was omitted, but this behavior is now deprecated.

Second, it would be better to initialize the `ndigit` array, like this:

```
int ndigit[10] = { 0 };
```

The for loop is superfluous because we can have initialization; it's also less readable than the initialization syntax, and it's also dangerous: the author doesn't calculate the count of the array using `sizeof(ndigits) / sizeof(ndigits[0])`, but he hardcodes its length, which may cause a buffer overrun when the length of the array is changed (decreased) and the hard-coded length value in the for loop is forgotten about.

Comment: I thought that    c - '0'    was subtracting the char code for 0, but as far as ASCII is concerned that value is zero? So, I did not understand how it was changing anything.

Comment: @sherrellbc Nah. `'0'` is ASCII 48. Get a better ASCII char code table.

Comment: Oh, I see. I was looking at the table entry for NULL.

Comment: The example comes from the C Programming Language by Kernighan and Ritchie.

Comment: @ouah Ouch. Sad. Still not good. (How *possibly* could K&R hardcode the length of the array?)

Comment: @H2CO3 maybe because the example is in chapter 1?

Comment: @ouah Possibly. I *still* don't like it.

Comment: So, that is to say, if an 'A' is read from some input file, and c = getchar() is used to read that character, c would equal 65? And in C++ the type char is actually used to represent 48 as 'A' rather than its integer counterpart?

Comment: @H2C03 I did not think that dynamic array sizes were possible in C.

Comment: @sherrellbc They are, but how does this have anything to do with the question?

Comment: @H2C03 You had just mentioned how the author hardcoded the array length. I just was unaware that dynamic array lengths were possible in C. Also, 3 posts up, am I correct in my statement?

Comment: @sherrellbc `sizeof()` is not a runtime construct, unless applied on VLAs. It evaluates to a compile-time constant. But since C99, you can also write `size_t length = some_length; int arr[length];`, but that's another thing.

Comment: @sherrellbc And I don't understand the comment you are referring to. How does C++ come into the picture at all? What do you mean by the statement that "a type is used to represent `'A'` instead of 48?" - Furthermore, you are still assuming that all system in the word uses ASCII, which is not true.

Comment: @H2C03 Perhaps then I should find a more updated PDF rather than one printed in 1988. No sense in learning from outdated material. Also, I thought that 'char' was a data type in C, not just C++, but I have yet to find any instance of this in the ebook.

Comment: I understand that not all systems use ASCII. For instance: int c = 'A', and char c = 'A'. And I mentioned C++ because you had in an earlier post about the promotion of getchar to an int (this post as been deleted).

Comment: @sherrellbc Yes, `char` is a data type in C and in C++ too. Character literals are of type `int` in C and of type `char` in C++. Don't try to always draw parallels between C and C++, especially not while you are just learning C, because they are ***very different*** languages, and always trying to reason something by "but this and this works like this in C++" will give you false impressions and result in wrong assumptions. Also, yes, K&R is good, but nowadays it's only good if you grab a more recent book in addition.

Answer (score 1):

The program computes the number of times a digit between 0 and 9 was introduced as input, how many white spaces and how many other characters were in the input.

```
++ndigit[c-'0'];
```

'0' - as integer is the ASCII code for 0. 
c - is the read character (its ASCII code)
 
c - '0' = the actual digit (between 0 and 9) represented by the ASCII code c.

For example '3'(ASCII) would be 3(digit=integer) + '0'(ASCII) 

So that's how you obtain the index in the array for your digit and you increment the number of times that digit showed up.